# Swift - Function to Get Local Approximate Sidereal Time

Tags: swift, macos, astronomy

Looking for a function to get current local approximate sidereal time. The method of computation may be seen here - http://aa.usno.navy.mil/faq/docs/GAST.php.

I have the current position's longitude in decimal with east being a positive number and west being a negative number and am looking for a way to get local approximate sidereal time from that.